# @angular/material no exported member 'OverlayContainer'

Tags: angular, angular-material2, angular-cdk

I'm trying to get custom theming working and everything is ok until I need to style the OverlayContainer for dialogs and modals. When I try to import OverlayContainer as per the documentation and various guides VS Code throws an error:

`Module '../node_modules/@angular/material/material"' has no exported member 'OverlayContainer'`)

I've tried searching through the node_modules folder in case its just in a different directory but it appears not.

What am I missing? Any help appreciated.

app.component.ts

```
import { OverlayContainer } from '@angular/material';
```

package.json

`"@angular/material": "^5.0.0-rc.2"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should try :

import {OverlayContainer} from "@angular/cdk/overlay";

all the "material agnostic" features have been moved to cdk repo.

Regards

Comment: Many thanks. I'm actually really embarassed as the material2 theming guide use ../cdk/overlay in the example, not sure how I missed it :(