# Upgrading to Angular version 13 cause some module errors and stylings

Tags: angular, user-interface, overlay, upgrade, angular-cdk

I upgraded from Angular 12 to Angular 13 and I notice some issues in there. The code is compiling without problems and the app is running. However, I will point to some of the errors (problems) that I noticed:

> Module '"@angular/cdk/overlay"' has no exported member 'OverlayModule'.

Another issue, is that some stylings changed by itself:
[image]

It was looking like this:

[image]

Here are my dependencies in the package.json file:

```html
{
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/schematics": "^13.0.4",
    "@angular/animations": "~13.0.3",
    "@angular/cdk": "^13.0.3",
    "@angular/common": "~13.0.3",
    "@angular/compiler": "~13.0.3",
    "@angular/core": "~13.0.3",
    "@angular/flex-layout": "^13.0.0-beta.36",
    "@angular/forms": "~13.0.3",
    "@angular/localize": "~13.0.3",
    "@angular/material": "^13.0.3",
    "@angular/material-moment-adapter": "^13.0.3",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~13.0.3",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~13.0.3",
    "@angular/router": "~13.0.3",
    "@asymmetrik/ngx-leaflet": "^8.1.0",
    "@asymmetrik/ngx-leaflet-markercluster": "^5.0.1",
    "@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap": "^10.0.0",
    "@popperjs/core": "^2.11.0",
    "@types/jquery": "^3.5.9",
    "@types/leaflet.markercluster": "^1.4.6",
    "angular-notifier": "^9.1.0",
    "bootstrap": "^5.1.3",
    "file-saver": "^2.0.5",
    "jquery": "^3.6.0",
    "jszip": "^3.7.1",
    "leaflet": "^1.7.1",
    "leaflet.markercluster": "^1.5.3",
    "material-icons": "^0.3.1",
    "ngb-modal": "^2.0.3",
    "primeicons": "^4.0.0",
    "primeng": "^10.0.0",
    "resize-observer-polyfill": "^1.5.1",
    "rxjs": "~6.5.4",
    "tslib": "^2.3.1",
    "web-animations-js": "^2.3.2",
    "zone.js": "~0.11.4"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "^13.0.4",
    "@angular/cli": "^13.0.4",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "~13.0.3",
    "@types/file-saver": "^2.0.1",
    "@types/jasmine": "~3.10.2",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.10",
    "@types/jszip": "^3.1.7",
    "@types/leaflet": "^1.7.6",
    "@types/node": "^16.11.11",
    "codelyzer": "^6.0.2",
    "jasmine-core": "~3.10.1",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~7.0.0",
    "karma": "^6.3.9",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~3.1.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~3.0.2",
    "karma-jasmine": "~4.0.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^1.7.0",
    "protractor": "~7.0.0",
    "ts-node": "~10.4.0",
    "tslint": "~6.1.3",
    "typescript": "^4.5.5"
  }
}
```

Lastly, there were also some errors with some imports like - FormsModule and ReactiveFormsModule from the @angular/forms.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [@angular/material no exported member 'OverlayContainer'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47716868/angular-material-no-exported-member-overlaycontainer)

Comment: you should try this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47716868/angular-material-no-exported-member-overlaycontainer

Comment: Please use Angular Interactive Upload Guide: https://update.angular.io/

Comment: @rikg93 I already followed this and there is nothing related to my issue in there.

Comment: @XCA, I tried to change OverlayModule with the OverlayContainer, but now receive the following error:
`Uncaught Error: Type OverlayContainer does not have 'ɵmod' property.`

Comment: I have a different issue in Angular 13. I placed a * in `mat-label`. It displays two *. It seems that angular 13 material or cdk causes it. No clue so far.

Comment: @Bigeyes I have never had such an issue and already terminated my contract for the company that I was doing the project. However, I found this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64809939/best-way-to-add-asterisk-to-mat-label-in-angular-material

Additionally, what I am doing for the '*' now, in my Vue project, is the following: ``:label="disableRequirements ? `${$t('label.email')}` : `${$t('label.email')}*`"``

Hope something of that helps, if not, you can provide us the code to reproduce.

Comment: @Vitomir, no worry. I found it. It is angular 13 material issue. It automatedly add *.[link](https://github.com/angular/components/commit/1568b3597236549b0669aee869f5f0875c18db4d)